# Error in drupal 8 to share images on facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph, drupal-8, meta-tags

I have the following error to try to adjust the sharing of articles on facebook: When I share the post, everything seems normal:

[share view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcQ5n.png)

But when I share, the image appears like this:

[in facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjWy2.png)
I don't have much knowledge, so I'm not really sure what's going on, I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the image link is being pulled with the wrong termination, even if it works in the browser, I think Facebook shouldn't be understanding as an image from what I'm seeing on facebook debug:

This: og:image  https://icarabe.org/sites/default/files/styles/750x499/public/img/2020-06/habib.png?itok=BPN7mY1R

Can someone help me?